# How to navigate to a directory chosen with Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, storage-access-framework

I've used [`OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) to let the user choose a directory to store app documents.
So my app can manage the documents there and it works as expected.

Now i'd like to let the user navigate to it (for the user i'd like to feel like 3rd-party file manager/application is launched with default directory opened).

Given i have a URI similar to `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:SomeDirectory` how can i open it?

I've tried to send an intent with uri and `ACTION_VIEW`, but no activity was able to handle it (code in Dart for Flutter):

```dart
var intent = AndroidIntent(
   action: 'action_view',
   data: directoryUri);
await intent.launch();
```

> 2022-04-08 23:53:58.402 I/flutter: PlatformException(error, No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:SomeDirectory (has extras) }, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:SomeDirectory (has extras) }

Comment: "how can i open it?" -- there is no "open a document tree" `Intent` in Android. "for the user i'd like to feel like 3rd-party file manager/application is launched with default directory opened" -- there is no requirement for the user to have chosen a document tree backed by a directory on the device's filesystem.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Comment: By "open" i mean launching the backed document provider app and navigating to the chosen resource identified by URI. In trivial case it's just a directory on the device.

Comment: "i mean launching the backed document provider app" -- I do not know what "the backed document provider app" means, sorry. Though I did make a mistake in my original comment: there is no "view a document tree" `Intent` in Android.